# Details about APPLICATION-FINDER-FN in sw-http

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, comet

I'm looking to do some synchronous web-programming in Common Lisp, and I'm rounding up options. One of them is [`sw-http`](https://github.com/lnostdal/SW-HTTP), an "HTTP server tailored for AJAX/Comet". The documentation seems to be a bit lacking because the only piece I could find tells you to

> Sub-class SERVER and set the APPLICATION-FINDER-FN slot to a callback
>   that generates your content.

There doesn't seem to be any notes or examples about what that callback should look like (some prodding told me that it should expect a `server` and a `connection` as arguments, but nothing about what it should return or do).

setting it to something naive like

```
(lambda (server conn) (declare (ignore server conn)) "Hello world")
```

doesn't seem to do anything, so I assume I either need to write to a stream somewhere or interact with the `server`/`connection` in some less-than-perfectly-obvious way.

Any hints?

Comment: Obviously, you have to write to the stream of `connection`. But looking at `sw-http` code, I wouldn't suggest using it for production, although it may be worth researching a way to develop something on top of it...

Comment: I believe Hunchentoot is the Common Lisp web server the cool kids are using these days.

Comment: P.S., I think I agree with @VsevolodDyomkin, this library isn't ready for prime time.

Comment: @Samuel - Aware, but AFAIK, [hucnchentoot isn't so good at Comet](http://lists.common-lisp.net/pipermail/tbnl-devel/2009-February/004622.html). Granted, that may have changed since that comment, but still.

Comment: Oh, of course, it makes sense that it wouldn't now that I think about it.

Comment: You can use some front-end server like Mongrel2 for terminating Comet connections, and Hunchentoot as an app server. It's pretty easy to interface between Mongrel2 and Lisp (here's the example code: https://github.com/vseloved/cl-mongrel2/blob/master/mongrel2.lisp - but beware, that it's not production tested)

Comment: No, I got sidetracked by other bullshit. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler takes a `connection` which has a `response` which has some `chunks`.

Presumably you're to add your content to the `chunks` (which are `octets`) of the `response` of the `connection`.  Luckily there are some helper methods defined to make this easier.

You might try this (I couldn't get SW-HTTP to compile so I can't):

```
(defun hello (server connection)
  (let*((response (cn-response connection))
        (chunks (rs-chunks response)))
    (queue-push chunks
                (mk-response-status-code 200)
    (queue-push chunks
                (mk-response-message-body "Hello cruel world"))))

(defclass my-server (server)
  ((application-finder-fn :initform #'hello)))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is `enqueue` from a specific package, or is that a notional function that should be part of `sw-http`?

Comment: @Inaimathi, that should probably have been queue-push from aromyxo, and the arguments are in the opposite order.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm tentatively accepting this, but it hasn't actually worked yet (I'll play around some more tomorrow and post results). Thank you :)